# How to print files names from file where awk is selecting values?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a .txt file having files names as

```
z1.cap
z2.cap
z3.cap
z4.cap
```

Sample data present in these files are like shown below,

```
OTR 25896 PAT210 $TREMD DEST

OFR 21475 NAT102 #TREMD DEST
```

then I'm using below code to print desired values from files.

```
while read file_name
do
echo "progressing with file :${file_name}"
cat ${file_name} | grep "PAT210" | awk -F' ' '$5 == "(DEST" { print $file_name, $1}' | uniq >> OUTPUT_FILE
```

Now I want output which consists of 2 fields like,

```
z1.cap OTR
z2.cap OFR
```

and so on...

But i'm getting ouputs like,

```
- OTR
- OFR
```

Any help is aprreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you want by reading the code that has problems. Can you explain why you find `z2.cap OFR` when the code looks for `PAT210`?

Comment: Inside the `awk` code, shell variables are not replaced. For a filename input you can use FILENAME, in other cases use `awk -v awkvariable=$shellvariable '...awkcode...'`.

Comment: @WalterA I am also at a loss as to what the OP is trying to achieve. It took some back and forth to get the question into its current state. Decided to leave well-enough alone.

Answer (score 1):

To access the filename that awk is currently processing use the builtin variable `FILENAME`

To bind other shell variables from your shell to variables in awk use:

```
awk -v var1=$shvar1 -v var2=$shvar2 'your awk code using var1 and var2'
```

Assuming `files.txt` contains your list of files and with zero understanding of what exactly you are trying to achieve:

```
for file_name in $(cat files.txt)
do
    echo "progressing with file :${file_name}"
    awk -F' ' '($5 == "DEST") && ($3=="PAT210") { print FILENAME, $1}' $file_name | uniq >> OUTPUT_FILE
done
```

I removed the cat and incorporated the grep into your awk. The cat was unnecessary since awk can read the file itself.

You can remove the for loop entirely by saying

```
awk -F' ' '($5 == "DEST") && ($3=="PAT210") { print FILENAME, $1}' $(<files.txt) | uniq >> OUTPUT_FILE
```

The `$(<files.txt)` will send each filename to awk.

Comment: Here, we need to traverse all the 4 files. i.e, z5.cap, z6.cap and so on. if you remove cat how we are traversing?

Comment: The way you have written it, `read file_name`  gets the names from user input.  I can modify it to read the names from the .txt file if you like.